# Do questions have to be directly about finding software?

Tags: discussion, scope

Probably a bit of a silly question and I expect the answer will be yes, but I will ask anyway...

Do questions have to be aimed at finding a piece of software? Or can they be related to software in general?

For example, can I ask a question about recommending a provider for 'software boxes', as in the physical packaging that a software application might be delivered in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3-letter-answer: Yes. SR is about recommending software – not "all about software". As it's pointed out [in our help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for questions asking for recommendations of **software** ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”. While this includes software libraries for development use, note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic – as are questions like “what technology to use for …?”

So 2-letter-answer to your follow-up questions: No, they can't be "related to software in general", and especially not to "physical packaging that a software application might be delivered in".

Comment: Thanks, as I assumed, but was worth a shot