# Are "Can I use X for Y" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I'm tempted to vote [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55543/evaluating-persistence-framework-to-use) as off-topic but cannot find any criteria on meta about this.

What do we do with questions of the form "I'm using X, can I do Y with it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO,** they are off-topic. Quoting from [our help center's on-topic page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, **“what software can I use to do …?”**

(emphasis mine). You see, it's not including "can I use this software to do …".

Further, see our [question quality guidelines](/q/336/185). Just quoting one chapter name: "What kind of application are you looking for?" – again, it's about "what application" – not the other way around.

Further relevant [scope](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) questions include:

- [Do questions have to be directly about finding software?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2592/185)
- **[Can I ask if a particular software will fit my needs?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1073/185)**

Answer (score 2):

If you have a question about X (in that case Spring Data JPA), then:

1. Refrain from asking on this site.
2. Go read the documentation about X (in that case https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).
3. The documentation or official website probably says whether X can be used for Y. If not:
4. Go to https://superuser.com/help/on-topic and familiarize yourself with that site's rules.
5. Search for X on that site, check whether your question is answered already. If not:
6. Post your question at https://superuser.com , be sure to include all necessary details per the site's rules: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask